# How to fix invalid argument supplied for foreach() php?

Tags: php

i tried to apply some of the existing samples found here in stackoverflow but the problem seems to be unsolved.

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*1000; 
$path = "upload/"; 
$count = 0;
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {  
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found}
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {         
                if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                    $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                    continue; // Skip large files
                }
                elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ) {
        $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
        ...
```

Comment: `$_FILES['files']['name']` is not array. That's why you are getting this error

Comment: Explain your question properly. What have you tried? What is the issue?

Comment: $_FILES['files']['name'] replace this code with $_FILES['files']. (i think if you submit form of multiple file)

Comment: `$_FILES['files']['name']` contain string value, use `$_FILES['files']` and check

Comment: ill try that @SantoshPatel

Comment: I think you are checking this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869998/file-upload-is-not-checking-for-the-existing-file. Check this link http://itsphptime.blogspot.in/2013/03/upload-image-file-in-php.html

Comment: [The PHP Manual contains some pretty good examples](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) of how to process file uploads [Even multiple file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) That should be your first port of call, not SO

Answer (score 0):

As urfusion said, $_FILES['files']['name'] is a string, not an array.

That you can do to iterate over all the filenames of submitted files is something like that:

```
if(is_array($_FILES['files']) && !empty($_FILES['files'])){ // if1
  foreach($_FILES['files'] as $file_index=>$file_value){
    if($file_index==='name'){ // if2
      echo $file_value;    // or do something with that name
    } // end if2
  } // end foreach
} // end if1
```